# Preview HTML divided by pages before print

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I need to make own preview print page (like google docs editor), before convert html to pdf,
like this: http://welcome.totheinter.net/autocolumn/sample10.html

After print or convert example page to pdf i would like this same effect (with this same header and footer, margins, fonts, sizes,...)

How to switch off browser header, footer and set ideal as preview page apperance with any web browser?

Comment: Please describe what you want to accomplish. For fear of being spammed with toxic waste, some people are not going to click such a link to an unknown destination. Furthermore, is it going to still be there still after 5 years of time? If not, the question becomes totally meaningless. Stackoverflow is a peer-built knowledge base. Otherwise - not having courage to follow the link -  I would like to comment that this could be a very interesting question!!!

Comment: I need to make WYSWIG web text (HTML) editor with styles, margins, headers, footers. This editor must have print preview before printing. In print preview i need to see exacly like on paper page view per page. 
My problem is how to turn off browser headers and footers in print page, how page break, how add own headers and footers in printed document.

I found some example how format html to make good print preview, with headers and footers, with pages like on print but i have problem with representation this same on paper printed from browser. 
(sorry for my english ;))

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can't switch off browsers' print header and footer on the client side (in Javascript) If you're converting this to PDF then PDF printer has to be configured to turn off headers and footers.

Secondly if you want page breaks, add this CSS:

```
@media print{
   .page{
      page-break-after:always;
   } 
}
```

Comment: "switch off browsers' print header and footer on the client side" - yes, but how to do this?